# Android Lint Shape not allowed here

Tags: android, android-actionbar, lint

I have a custom toolbar icon (I needed a toolbar icon with text always visible next to it).

When I inspect my code with Lint, I receive the warning that shape is not allowed here. As much as I understand, I should enclose the shape with item tag, but once I do that the ripple effect is not working on my custom toolbar icon. This is my current code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <padding
            android:bottom="5dp"
            android:left="5dp"
            android:right="5dp"
            android:top="5dp" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    </shape>
</ripple>
```

What would be a correct approach to this? I tried moving the shape to a separate drawable file and then referencing it with `<item android:drawable:"@drawable/shape"/>`
and it loads the correct icon and layout, but ripple is gone then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, but using just the following for a background of my custom toolbar icon layout does the trick and keeps Lint from complaining.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
</ripple>
```